Multiple one-way ANOVAs, or are there better ways?
I analyze peptide content by mass spectrometry. I do 6 injections (replicates) for 4 experimental conditions (factor), and measure signal intensity (response). Usually, I would use a one-way ANOVA. However, the injected solution contains four different peptides, all with naturally different signal intensities. Just using a single peptide's response would not use all the data available. I could do four ANOVAs, but I wonder if there is some better way? What I want to know is essentially "Which condition is, as a whole, the better?".
Example head and tail of the data:


The replicates are blocks then?

Not quite sure, to be honest. I think no, as each peptide has its own measured signal intensity. Its not an average response that is affected by both "peptide" and "condition". I've added example data in the question.

Is injection something you are interested in? That is the effect of injection and condition on the response? Or does injection represent some random variation which is not of interested but should be modeled?

No, I'm not interested in the injections themselves. I simply inject the same solution with the same peptides several times, and vary only the experimental condition in the way the peptide response is measured. There will be some natural variation between injections, however.

It sounds like injection is a block then, since it's the same injection which is used multiple times with different conditions. Is this true? Why does your picture show each injection having exactly one condition? Is every injection tested against every condition or is each injection tested against exactly one condition multiple times?

Sorry, I find it a bit hard to explain. One injection (ie., measurement of peptide signals, of which there are four peptides) gets one condition. Each condition gets six of these, supposed to be identical, injections. An analogy would be to think of the injections as very similar people who are each exposed to one of four conditions, and where we measure several blood markers (peptide signal).

Since there is a single, shared response variable for all comparisons you intend to do, I would try and incorporate this into a single model. This has the advantage of greater power and easier model diagnostics.
I think what you're looking for is just a two-way ANOVA:

The first grouping variable is the condition the sample is subject to;
The second grouping variable is the peptide;
If you suspect the differences between the conditions to depend on the peptide, you can include an interaction between the two grouping variables.

If you can assume measurements within an "injection" to be independent, that's all. If measurements within an injection are likely correlated, you can account for this dependency with a random effect.
Lastly, you should have to look at the conditional distribution of the response using residual diagnostic plots. Having some experience with signal intensities, they are usually strongly right-skewed. You could try modelling the log-intensity and see if the model assumptions of a regular ANOVA hold up, or you could assume a different probability distribution (e.g., gamma).

Assuming there is indeed strong right skew, in R, these options look like this:
# Two-way ANOVA
M1 <- lm(log(Response) ~ Peptide + Condition, data = data)

# Two-way ANOVA with interaction
M2 <- lm(log(Response) ~ Peptide * Condition, data = data)

# Two-way ANOVA with random effect for injection
library("lme4")
M3 <- lmer(log(Response) ~ Peptide + Condition + (1 | Injection), 
            data = data)

# Same as the previous, but assuming a conditional gamma distribution
library("lme4")
M4 <- glmer(Response ~ Peptide + Condition + (1 | Injection), 
            family = Gamma(link = "log"), data = data)

For $\mathcal{M}_1$–$\mathcal{M}_3$, you can plot the residuals with plot(model). For $\mathcal{M}_4$, you can use simulated quantile residuals, like the ones provided by the DHARMa package.
You can perform pairwise comparison as needed with the emmeans package, it has several very helpful vignettes.

Indeed, you need a 2-way ANOVA. In fact you have a very nice full-factorial experimental design, with 6 replicates for each combination of factors (4 categorical peptides, 4 categorical conditions). This type of design and associated analysis is also known as DOE (Design of Experiment); e.g. see here. R offers various packages for DOE (e.g. see here). A good DOE analysis will give you all the answers you need (analysis of variance, p-values for the various factors -including interaction terms-, plots, plots for confirming your assumptions -normality of residuals, and homoscedasticity of the residuals as a function of the fit-, main effects and interaction plots, response optimization, etc). The term DOE is much more common in Engineering (my field), but is also well used in Genetics and Biology (I assume your field; e.g. see here).
Note that DOE is not a different solution to the ANOVA suggested by @Frans Rodenburg; it is simply a different packaging of the exact same method (multi-way ANOVA), but one I find more intuitive/informative (matter of taste) for exactly the types of experiments you are conducting.

+1. I'll just add this is sometimes not called two-way anova in the DOE literature (in case the post author doesn't see it named as such) but instead what you describe as a factorial design. But mathematically they are the same.
